# Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo una petición super basica a un servidor de una api con fetch y me marca este error...

No entiendo que esta mal de por si estoy copiando tal cual como sale en la documentacion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estás tratando de transformar el resultado de `data` a un objeto json, sin embargo lo que viene en `data` es un html o xml (que claramente empieza con un caracter `<`).